# Spark readStream from Kafka Group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am working with Spark 3.3.0 and kafka 3.2.0. I want use group id in readStream but data is lost when spark is not running. how can i stop dataflow when spark stops ?
**My code;**

```
val df = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", x.x.x.x)
  .option("subscribe", "topic-name")
  .option("kafka.group.id","group_name")
  .option("enable.auto.commit",true)
  .load()
```

Comment: Your code to use a group is fine. What do you mean "stop Dataflow when Spark stops"?

Comment: I am starting one scala with this code and later i am killing this shell. After 15 minutes i am starting another scala with this code. data lost in 15 minutes of non-working. These datas are not coming console.

Comment: You do understand how Kafka consumer groups work, right? If you consume, then stop, then offsets will be committed and not read again until you reset the group. That's not a Spark issue. Also data is not deleted/lost within those few minutes

Comment: I am understanding you but offsets dont be committed after read again and i dont reset The group

Comment: What do you mean? In Spark documentation - [`enable.auto.commit` doesn't do anything](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations). And still, what do you mean by  "data is lost"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Kafka configuration:

`log.retention.hours=100`

This allows Kafka to keep the data for 100 hours and doesn't lose data when spark is not running